# pseudocode to convert english to constraint

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

This is not a technical question, but more curious if anyone has seen any software that converts english rules into linear constraints for MILP solvers?  The rules would be industry specific and not general, thus for example specifying pseudocode for a shift scheduling problem (ex: an employee cannot work 3 shift days in a row) for warehouses or in healthcare setting, so not industry generic.

Comment: Have you tried chatGPT :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement rules like as in the example above are turned into propositional logic. In commercial software that have something called rules engine a truth table is used to convert such rules to logical flow.
Any automation/workflow based software with rules engine may have this capability, like Capterra, process marker, SAP may have that. If searching on Google suggested search string is 'sentence based rules to logic or constraints'

Answer (score 6):

I tried [chatGPT](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-zoo-openai-chatgpt-alex-fleischer/) with my [Zoo, bus and optimization example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6).

[image: question]

and I got

[image]

and then

[image]